# get rows with largest value in grouping

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that I group according to an `id`-column. For each group I want to get the row (the whole row, not just the value) containing the max value. I am able to do this by first getting the max value for each group, then create a filter array and then apply the filter on the original dataframe. Like so,

```
import pandas as pd

# Dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                   'other_value' : ['a', 'e', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'f' ,'a' ,'c', 'e', 'f'],
                   'value' : [1, 3, 5, 2, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6, 1, 7, 3]
                   })

# Get the max value in each group
df_max = df.groupby('id')['value'].max()

# Create row filter
row_filter = [df_max[i]==v for i, v in zip(df['id'], df['value'])]

# Filter
df_target = df[row_filter]
df_target
Out[58]: 
    id other_value  value
2    1           b      5
5    2           d      6
7    3           f      4
10   4           e      7
```

This solution works, but somehow seems overly cumbersome. Does anybody know of a nicer way to do this. Preferably a oneliner. Regarding potential duplicates, I'll deal with those later :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) if need select only one max value:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('id')['value'].idxmax()]
print (df)
    id other_value  value
2    1           b      5
5    2           d      6
7    3           f      4
10   4           e      7
```

If multiple max values and want seelct all rows by `max` values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                   'other_value' : ['a', 'e', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'f' ,'a' ,'c', 'e', 'f'],
                   'value' : [1, 3, 5, 2, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6, 1, 7, 7]
                   })
```

---

```
print (df)
    id other_value  value
0    1           a      1
1    1           e      3
2    1           b      5
3    2           b      2
4    2           a      5
5    2           d      6
6    3           b      2
7    3           f      4
8    4           a      6
9    4           c      1
10   4           e      7
11   4           f      7

df = df[df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('max') == df['value']]
print (df)
    id other_value  value
2    1           b      5
5    2           d      6
7    3           f      4
10   4           e      7
11   4           f      7
```

Comment: Too easy :) Thanks.