# Get row of maximum value in pandas.groupBy without apply in dataframe with DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `pandas.Dataframe` with a `DatetimeIndex`. The data are sampled every 30 minutes (can be different). I want to resample the data every hour and, for each group, I want to extract the row with the highest value on a specific column.

E.g.

```
                     WindDir  WindSpeed  Temperature  CloudHgt
Date                                                          
2020-01-01 00:20:00    150.0        3.6          5.0     213.0
2020-01-01 00:50:00    150.0        3.1          5.0     213.0
2020-01-01 01:20:00    130.0        4.1          5.0     183.0
2020-01-01 01:50:00    130.0        3.6          5.0     183.0
2020-01-01 02:20:00    130.0        3.1          4.0     244.0
2020-01-01 02:50:00    140.0        3.6          4.0     366.0
2020-01-01 03:20:00    130.0        2.6          3.0   99999.0
2020-01-01 03:50:00    160.0        2.6          3.0      91.0
2020-01-01 04:20:00    170.0        2.6          3.0      61.0
2020-01-01 04:50:00    180.0        2.6          3.0      30.0
2020-01-01 05:20:00    150.0        1.5          3.0     183.0
2020-01-01 05:50:00    190.0        2.1          3.0      30.0
2020-01-01 06:20:00    190.0        2.1          3.0     122.0
2020-01-01 06:50:00    220.0        1.5          3.0     152.0
2020-01-01 07:20:00    230.0        2.1          3.0     213.0
2020-01-01 07:50:00    230.0        1.5          3.0     244.0
2020-01-01 08:20:00    999.0        1.0          3.0     335.0
2020-01-01 08:50:00    999.0        0.5          3.0     335.0
2020-01-01 09:20:00    120.0        2.1          3.0     335.0
```

And I want to resample this obtaining:

```
                     WindDir  WindSpeed  Temperature  CloudHgt
Date                                                          
2020-01-01 00:00:00    150.0        3.6          5.0     213.0
2020-01-01 01:00:00    130.0        4.1          5.0     183.0
2020-01-01 02:00:00    130.0        3.6          5.0     183.0
2020-01-01 03:00:00    140.0        3.6          4.0     366.0
2020-01-01 04:00:00    160.0        2.6          3.0      91.0
2020-01-01 05:00:00    180.0        2.6          3.0      30.0
2020-01-01 06:00:00    190.0        2.1          3.0      30.0
2020-01-01 07:00:00    230.0        2.1          3.0     213.0
2020-01-01 08:00:00    230.0        1.5          3.0     244.0
2020-01-01 09:00:00    120.0        2.1          3.0     335.0
```

I read several questions on SO such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815893/get-rows-with-largest-value-in-grouping), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842287/select-rows-with-highest-value-from-groupby), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334767/get-the-row-corresponding-to-the-max-in-pandas-groupby) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459325/python-pandas-dataframe-select-row-by-max-value-in-group).
Hoever most of these focus on Dataframes without DatetimeIndex for which the order of the samples does not matter. Also, since Groupby re-labels the group with the start-time of that group, looking for samples with the same index is unfeasible.

I found a working solution using `apply(lambda group: group.nlargest(1, columns=column))`. However this is extremely slow on large Dataframes.

At the moment my code looks something like:

```py
# define grouper
grouper = pd.Grouper(freq='1H', offset='30min')

# aggregate data (except wind dir)
resampled = (data
             .groupby(grouper)
             .apply(lambda group: group.nlargest(1, columns=column))
             .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
             ).shift(30,'min')
```

**Is there a better solution that does not uses the `apply` function as it is extremely slow?**

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(df.index.ceil(freq="H")).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.WindDir.idxmax(), :])
#                      WindDir  WindSpeed  Temperature  CloudHgt
# Date                                                          
# 2020-01-01 01:00:00    150.0        3.6          5.0     213.0
# 2020-01-01 02:00:00    130.0        4.1          5.0     183.0
# 2020-01-01 03:00:00    140.0        3.6          4.0     366.0
# 2020-01-01 04:00:00    160.0        2.6          3.0      91.0
# 2020-01-01 05:00:00    180.0        2.6          3.0      30.0
# 2020-01-01 06:00:00    190.0        2.1          3.0      30.0
# 2020-01-01 07:00:00    220.0        1.5          3.0     152.0
# 2020-01-01 08:00:00    230.0        2.1          3.0     213.0
# 2020-01-01 09:00:00    999.0        1.0          3.0     335.0
# 2020-01-01 10:00:00    120.0        2.1          3.0     335.0
```

Comment: The output doesn't look exactly the OP's expected output - your dates start with 01:00:00 and end with 10:00:00 - the OP's start with 00:00:00 and end with 09:00:00.

Comment: @user17242583, OP might need to use `floor` instead of `ceil`

Comment: On a different note, what purpose does the `:` after the `idxmax()` serve? When I remove it, it doesn't change the output.

Comment: @user17242583, the `:` is for retrieving all columns. removing it should not affect the output but it's just my habit

Comment: @user17242583, compare `df.groupby(df.index.floor(freq="H")).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.WindDir.idxmax(), ["WindSpeed", "CloudHgt"]])` for example

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I played around with that and found that you can even do bizzare stuff like `x.loc[x.WindDir.idxmax(), 'WindSpeed':'CloudHgt']`